# full screen camera in ios

Tags: ios, camera

I'm using the following code so the user can take a pic:

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Is there a way to make the camera occupy the hole screen?

Comment: What part of the screen is being occupied now?

Comment: At the top with the flash settings and the change front/back buttons. At the bottom with a yellow flash button, the trigger white button and the cancel one.

Comment: That is the default appearance of the UIImagePickerController I don't think this can be changed.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is the default implementation of UIImagePickerController which includes camera controls.

Try turning these off by setting `showsCameraControls` to `NO`.

If you want to add your own controls, use `cameraOverlayView`.

Comment: Setting `showsCameraControls` to `NO` doesn't make the camera preview full screen. The preview is still the same size, and the rest of the screen is black.